# Basic installation of React using the <script> tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, installation

I am doing Bucky Robert's (The New Boston) tutorial on React (hyperlink in the code below).

I'm stuck at the beginning, with just trying to install/load React with the  tag instead of using local files. I get two error messages:

1. TypeError: t(...).Object is undefined[Learn More] browser.min.js:8:31612
2. SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Learn More] test.html:19:24

I bet my problem is pretty basic, but I spent a lot of time trying to figure out what's going on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!--The tutorial that I'm trying to do https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2NLgQMs2hOw&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBuKtLgPR_zWYnrwv-JllpA&index=2-->
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="example"></div>

    <script>
        ReactDOM.render(<h1>test2</h1>, document.getElementById('example'));
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Basically, I just want to know what the non-buggy version of my code would be so I can do the tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching on the Internet and asking other people, here is what I found.

1. TypeError: t(...).Object is undefined[Learn More] browser.min.js:8:31612

This issue is related with  tags I provided. I was able to solve the problem by using this instead:

```
<script src= "https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src= "https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```

2. SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Learn More] test.html:19:24

As was pointed out: I was missing the "marking" of the code with

```
<script type="text/babel">
```

Here is the full code, without the two bugs I had:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!--https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html-->
    <script src= "https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js">                       </script>
    <script src= "https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="example"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
        ReactDOM.render(<h1>test2</h1>, document.getElementById('example'));
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script element doesn't contain regular JavaScript and you omitted the `type` attribute to show what it does contain.

Comment: Thanks Quentin. I added the type attribute. As for the non-regular JS, this line should theorically take care of it: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.min.js"></script> It is already in the code but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Babel only transpiles the code marked for transpiling. It won't touch stuff marked up as regular JS.

Comment: Thanks. I really don't know how to mark the code for transpiling though. What would you do or change, Quentin?

Comment: @user1975126 — As I said: You use the `type` attribute (just like it shows in the video you linked to).